# get process ID of PowerShell process

Tags: powershell

How would I know the process ID (PID) of the current PowerShell process?

```
Copy-Item \\APPSRVR02\DocExport\*.csv \\APPSRVRWPA\d$\DocImport\ImportFiles\
Remove-Item \\APPSRVRAP02\DocExport\*.csv
```

Some command to know PID of the process that is executing the above statements.

Answer (score 43):

Powershell has a concept called [Automatic Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx).

These are variables which the host defines when it starts up, so if you want to know the ID of the powershell process you are running in you can just type `$PID` and it will output the ID of the powershell process you are running within.  Depending on what you need the process ID for that should work for you.

Comment: That's the preferred solution, but for completeness - $PID is not available inside a .psm1 file.  There you're stuck with `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Id`

Comment: It's also doesn't seem available on pwsh CLI, when the shell was started from another script.

Answer (score 5):

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID
```

per [get process ID of PowerShell process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771124/get-process-id-of-powershell-process#comment126989566_40771506)