# Powershell kill all Powershell windows that are open besides the current one

Tags: powershell, command

```
Get-Process powershell | Format-table -Property Id -HideTableHeaders -Force | out-string -OutVariable "a"
foreach ($a in $tre) {stop-process $tre}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get process ID of PowerShell process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771124/get-process-id-of-powershell-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler, your script fragment `foreach ($a in $tre)` has the wrong order,
should be `foreach ($tre in $a)` but that wouldn't exclude the current powershell.

Try this:

```
Get-Process powershell | Where-Object ID -ne $PID | Stop-Process
```

Answer (score 0):

$rtrtrt = (get-random)

Get-Process powershell | Format-table -Property name, Id -HideTableHeaders -OutVariable "zaz"

$zaz = $zaz | out-string

$zaz = $zaz -replace "   ", " "

$zaz = $zaz -replace "  ", " "

$zaz = $zaz -replace "powershell $pid", ""

$zaz=$zaz -replace "powershell", "stop-process -force"

echo $zaz >$env:temp\$rtrtrt.ps1

&"$env:temp\$rtrtrt.ps1"

IF(!(Test-Path "$env:temp\$rtrtrt.ps1")) {echo "#"} else {Remove-Item "$env:temp\$rtrtrt.ps1" -recurse}

I made that up but yours looks much better
thank you

```
enter code here
```

I'm gonna use yours obviously

Get-Process powershell | Where-Object ID -ne $PID | Stop-Process