# PID returned by $$ in Bash for Windows (Git-Bash) is wrong

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash, pid

In Bash on any Unix-based OS, one can use `$$` to get the PID of the current shell. However it doesn't work in Bash for Windows (a.k.a. Git-Bash, which is installed with Git).

For example, right now on Windows 10, I have only one Bash window open. `echo $$` prints 1294, but the Task Manager says 7296 for `git-bash.exe` (the shell) and 12832 for `mintty.exe` (the terminal emulator).

What I want is to be able to kill a Bash script (running in a Bash window) from a separate Batch script (executed by `cmd.exe`), by reading the PID written in a text file by the Bash script. I have all the pieces of the puzzle, except a way to write the right PID from Bash (the Batch script says `ERROR: The process "1294" not found.`)

How can I achieve this?

**Edit**: After more tests, it seems `$!` also behaves unreliably.

**Edit 2**: Minimal reproduction of the problem:

`script.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo $$ >> /tmp/pid.txt
echo "Saved \"$$\" in PID file. Now going to sleep..."
sleep 86400
```

prints `Saved "2080" in PID file. Now going to sleep...`

`kill.bat`:

```
@for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%TEMP%\pid.txt) do (
    taskkill /pid %%a
)
@del %TEMP%\pid.txt
```

prints `ERROR: The process "2080" not found.`

Comment: I know it should, but it doesn't. (Note: The one killing the Bash script is a Batch script (executed by `cmd.exe`), not a Bash script. I will update my question to add this detail.)

Comment: This might help: [get process ID of PowerShell process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40771506/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
echo $$ >> /tmp/pid.txt
```

Try following to get Windows PID:

```
ps -p $$ | awk 'NR ==2{print $4}' > /tmp/pid.txt
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! It looks like Bash is using different PIDs than the actual ones and keeps a mapping between the two. Do you know why?

Comment: Git-bash is based on msys2, which tries to emulate Linux architecture. That may be why the process ID occupies a different namespace.